# EF synchronic savings of local and remote database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, synchronization

I have a local and remote database which are accessed with EF. The databases are in sync at initial state.

Now I want to save the changes done locally, also save on the remote database. This should be possible without downloading the whole remote database?.

Can I just change the connection string of the context and then call SaveChanges() on remote?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework).

Comment: this does sync, but i requires to download and upload the whole tables also if i change only one row.

Comment: my fault: i have to set SyncDirectionOrder to Download when i want to update the remote database!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a job for the entity framework. You can just use [SQL server replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) to sync changes in database level without changing your application .Your best option will be to use [transitional replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917706.aspx) which sync only the updates instead of snapshot .